# MYSQL is not returning DISTINCT values from database (php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the following code to return distinct Raceid's form my database

```
$distinctraceid = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT DISTINCT `raceid` FROM tom_cards ORDER BY raceid');
while ($distinctraceid2  = mysqli_fetch_array($distinctraceid)) {
     echo $distinctraceid2['raceid']."<br />";
}
```

the output though shows all ids?

> 621441 621441 621442 621441 621442 621443 621441 621442 621443 621444
>   621441

Table scheme is

```
ID int(255) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
raceid int(11) NO NULL
Date varchar(250) YES NULL
Racetime varchar(25) NO NULL
```

Comment: `distinct` works.  This suggests that you are either running a different query or that the data is stored as strings and contains hidden characters.

Comment: I have posted scheme- its the exact code and i have stored it as int so its just a number

Comment: note as well i just ran it in phpmyadmin directly and worked fine its just the code above

Comment: Could you try `DISTINCT(raceid)`? This is a very odd situation. My guess is that mysqli sanitizes the query

Comment: I just ran it like this = $distinctraceid = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT DISTINCT (raceid) as raceid FROM tom_cards ORDER BY raceid'); - having the same results

Comment: Why not grouping in stead of DISTINCT? `SELECT  raceid FROM tom_cards GROUP by raceid ORDER BY raceid ` it will not impact performance and also does what you want

Comment: group by worked!!!! how very strange?!?!

Comment: @emmaperkins Could you please post some of your actual data, I want to get to the bottom of this strange issue. I have tried to come up with the dummy dataset that yields the same result, but it always works as expected

Comment: Will do but away from computer now untill tomorrow - will post first thing

Answer (score 0):

replace your query with

```
SELECT DISTINCT tc.`raceid` FROM tom_cards AS tc ORDER BY tc.raceid ASC
```

it may work.